# Raspberry PI as printer

Tags: usb, windows, printing

I am wondering whether RasPI can be connected to a Windows PC through USB and appear to Windows as a printer. I wanted to process the PRINT command from Windows differently, say send that data to a webservice rather than printing it.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is your goal of the application? Which webservice do you want to relay to?

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi acts as a Host for USB and not as a device. The same thing happens to the Windows Machine. The best option is probably using a Network Printer Service, like lpd, and interconnect the two hosts using ethernet + TCP/IP.